# Different results on a variadic template example among gcc, clang and msvc - can anyone explain?

Tags: c++11, gcc, clang, variadic-templates, msvc12

I needed to make a function that takes a function pointer with variable arguments and some fixed arguments after them and could not make it work on Visual Studio 2013. I assumed that maybe Visual Studio 2013 was missing something which is often a case and made a minimal example that did what I needed and tried it against gcc and clang. And I got totally different results on all three compilers. So the questions which I'd like to resolve are:

1. Is my example valid at all? If not what am I doing wrong?
2. If my example is valid, any hints on the behavior of gcc and clang (lets count msvc out since it is a black box)?

The example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
    void work(int first, int second, int third)
    {
        std::cout << "0: " << first << ",1: " << second << ",2: " << third << std::endl;
    }
    void work_with_double(double first, int second, int third, int fourth)
    {
        std::cout << "0: " << first << ",1: " << second << ",2: " << third << ",3: " << fourth << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename ... argument_types>
void invoke_foo(foo* instance, int first, int second, int third, void (foo::*method)(argument_types ... arguments, int, int, int), argument_types ... arguments)
{
    (instance->*method)(arguments ..., first, second, third);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    foo instance;
    invoke_foo(&instance, 1, 2, 3, &foo::work); // gcc ok, clang err, msvc 2013 err
    invoke_foo<>(&instance, 1, 2, 3, &foo::work); // gcc ok, clang err, msvc 2013 err
    invoke_foo(&instance, 1, 2, 3, &foo::work_with_double, 1.0); // gcc err, clang ok, msvc 2013 err
    invoke_foo<double>(&instance, 1, 2, 3, &foo::work_with_double, 1.0); // gcc err, clang err, msvc 2013 ok
    return 0;
}
```

**Modified snippet that makes Visual Studio 2015 (w/o updates) crash**

If `invoke_foo` is made as a member function of an object, Visual Studio 2015 crashes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct foo
{
    void work(int first, int second, int third, int fourth, int fifth, int sixth, int seventh, int eight)
    {
        std::cout << "0: " << first << ",1: " << second << ",2: " << third << std::endl;
    }
    void work_with_double(double firstExtra, int first, int second, int third, int fourth, int fifth, int sixth, int seventh, int eight)
    {
        std::cout << "0: " << first << ",1: " << second << ",2: " << third << ",3: " << fourth << std::endl;
    }
};

struct bar
{

};

struct wrapper
{

    template <typename T> struct non_deduced { using type = T; };
    template <typename T> using non_deduced_t = typename non_deduced<T>::type;

    template<typename ... argument_types>
    std::shared_ptr<bar> invoke_foo(int first, int second, int third, int fourth, int fifth, int sixth, int seventh, int eight, void (foo::*method)(non_deduced_t<argument_types>... arguments, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int), argument_types ... arguments)
    {
        (foo_.get()->*method)(arguments ..., first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh, eight);
        return nullptr;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<foo> foo_ = std::move(std::unique_ptr<foo>(new foo));

};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    wrapper instance;
    instance.invoke_foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, &foo::work);
    instance.invoke_foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, &foo::work_with_double, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: you could make `argument_types` [non deduced](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/660505f38dece0c5) explicitly inside that function signature

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki thanks, this makes it work on msvc which is what I needed.

Comment: but I'm curious to see the answer

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki me too - honestly I expected at least gcc and clang to behave the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in each case is that the compiler is trying to infer `argument_types` from the `method` argument, which is illegal as variadic template parameters can only be inferred when they are at the end of an argument list.

```
void (foo::*method)(argument_types ... arguments, int, int, int)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't infer here
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ because of these
```

The workaround is to protect `argument_types` from being deduced in this context, using a helper like `identity`:

```
template<class T> struct identity { using type = T; };
template<class T> using identity_t = typename identity<T>::type;

// ...

template<typename ... argument_types>
void invoke_foo(foo* instance, int first, int second, int third,
    void (foo::*method)(identity_t<argument_types> ... arguments, int, int, int), argument_types ... arguments)
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^ fix here
```

---

Is this a bug in your code, or in the compilers? Actually, it's a bug in the compilers (yes, all of them); the question is whether a parameter pack appearing within a function type and not at the end of an argument list is a non-deduced context. The relevant part of the standard is [[temp.deduct.type]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type), which states:

> 5 - The non-deduced contexts are: [...]
>
> - A function parameter pack that does not occur at the end of the parameter-declaration-list.
>
> 6 - When a type name is specified in a way that includes a non-deduced context, all of the types that comprise that type name are also non-deduced. However, a compound type can include both deduced and non-deduced types.

Here, `argument_types` is in a non-deduced context when deducing the type of `method`, but a deduced context when deducing the types for the trailing arguments of `invoke_foo`.

Another compiler you could test is ICC (Intel C++ Compiler); ICC rejects the first two forms and accepts the last two, the exact opposite to gcc. The reason that compilers can be so different in their behavior is that dealing with this kind of code is essentially a matter of error handling, specifically recognising when template parameters appear in non-deduced contexts and using the types deduced elsewhere instead. The compilers are (each in their own way) recognising that `argument_types` cannot be deduced within `method`, but failing to realise or accept that it can be deduced elsewhere.

Specifically, it appears that:

- gcc assumes that if it cannot deduce `argument_types` from `method`, it must be empty;
- clang assumes that if `argument_types` is deduced to be empty or explicitly specified, this must be an error;
- MSVC is unable to let the deduction of `argument_types` override the failure to deduce it, but is OK if it is explicitly specified;
- ICC assumes that if `argument_types` is deduced to be empty, this must be an error.

Comment: @ecatmur, well I was thinking this is the reason, but sadly the interface methods to whom I pass the pointer are made in such a way that the common pack is at the end:( But still, since I explicitly state that here is a pattern, in this case `int, int, int` at the end of the variable argument pack, what makes it impossible to deduce the pack itself (I guess I am just not seeing something)? I'd be thankful if you could explain that.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis updated - hope I've answered your question.

Comment: yeah, thanks for the effort, this made things clearer for me:)

Comment: Just FYI - msvc 2015  crashes with the fix:D

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis hmm, it works for me (version 19.00.23506) and online at http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ (version 19.00.23720.0). What crash do you get?

Comment: My original sample was a bit different, the template method was a member function for a struct (and that does crash, while a plain method does not). I'll post the crashing version in my post and send a bug to VS :)

Comment: the sample in the edit does not crash in the cloud compiler (I have simply Visual Studio 2015, with no updates), so I assume this has been fixed during the updates:) Eh, hoped to report a bug for VS:D